# Why do matplotlib transforms not work as expected?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to move from data coordinates to axes coordinates in matplotlib.

Here is my code:

```
  a, b = (.5,2)
  x = np.linspace(-1,4,100)
  y = [psi(xv,a,b) for xv in x]
  plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
  ax = plt.gca()
  point = (a,1)
  display = (369, 316.8)
  trans1 = ax.transData.transform([0,0])
  print (trans1)
  trans = ax.transData.inverted().transform(trans1)
  print (trans)
  trans = ax.transAxes.inverted().transform(trans1)
  print (trans)
  plt.plot(trans[0], trans[1], 'ro')
  plt.plot(0,0, 'ro', transform=ax.transData)
  plt.plot(x,y, lw=3)
  plt.axhline(y = 1, color = 'r', linestyle = '--', lw=3, xmax=.3)
  plt.title('Psi Function', fontsize=30)
  plt.yticks([0, .2, .4, .6, .8, 1],['0','.2','','','','A'], fontsize = 'x-large')
  plt.xticks([-1, 0, 0.5, 2, 3, 4], ['','0', 'a', 'b', '', ''])
  plt.ylabel('$\Psi$', fontsize=25)
  plt.xlabel('$x$', fontsize=25)
  plt.grid()
```

The crucial bit of code I am concerned about is :

```
  trans1 = ax.transData.transform([0,0])
  print (trans1)
  trans = ax.transData.inverted().transform(trans1)
  print (trans)
  trans = ax.transAxes.inverted().transform(trans1)
  print (trans)
```

I am first transforming the data points (0,0) into screen coordinates and then trying to transform them back into both data coordinates, printing the result, and transforming them into axes cooredinates and expecting to get two different coordinates. I know (0,0) should be correct for data coordinates but the axes doesn't begin at (0,0) so they should be different and I would expect values greater than zero.

I am using matplotlib 3.5.1 so I am not sure if there is a problem with my version or not.

[image]

I edited my code to show:

```
ax.set_xlim(0,2)
ax.set_ylim(0,1.1)

trans1 = ax.transData.transform([0,0])
print (trans1)
trans = ax.transData.inverted().transform(trans1)
print (trans)
trans = ax.transAxes.inverted().transform(trans1)
```

and the results I got were:

```
[90. 45.]
[ 0.00000000e+00 -2.77555756e-17]
[0. 0.]
```

so really effectively still no change.

Comment: Matplotlib and python in general is not compiled code, so it cannot read ahead in your code and see what your x and y limits are going to be in the future.  When you make the print command, the x and y limits are from 0 to 1.

Comment: So what is the point of ax.transAxes then?

Comment: It's the transform from data space to pixel space.  But it can't read the future.  Put your print statements after your `plot(x, y)`.  https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html

Comment: I tried putting it just before the plt.grid() but I got the same result.

Comment: Sorry, I should have caught that.  You need to trigger an axes relim before you call the transform if you want it to report the final pixel location.  `plt.gcf().draw_without_rendering()` will do that.  However, you rarely, if ever need to know the pixel location of an object, so there is probably a better way to do what you want.  However, what that is isn't exactly clear from your question.