# Transform from data to figure coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib, coordinate-transformation

Similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29107800/5472354), I would like to transform my data coordinates to figure coordinates. Unfortunately, the [transformation tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html) doesn't seem to talk about it. So I came up with something analogous to the [answer by wilywampa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40475221/5472354), but for some reason, there is something wrong and I can't figure it out:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import ConnectionPatch

t = [
    0, 6.297, 39.988, 46.288, 79.989, 86.298, 120.005, 126.314, 159.994,
    166.295, 200.012, 206.314, 240.005, 246.301, 280.05, 286.35, 320.032,
    326.336, 360.045, 366.345, 480.971, 493.146, 1080.117, 1093.154, 1681.019,
    1692.266, 2281.008, 2293.146, 2881.014, 2893.178, 3480.988, 3493.149,
    4080.077, 4092.298, 4681.007, 4693.275, 5281.003, 5293.183, 5881.023,
    5893.188, 6481.002, 6492.31
]
y = np.zeros(len(t))


fig, (axA, axB) = plt.subplots(2, 1)
fig.tight_layout()
for ax in (axA, axB):
    ax.set_frame_on(False)
    ax.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

axA.plot(t[:22], y[:22], c='black')
axA.plot(t[:22], y[:22], 'o', c='#ff4500')
axA.set_ylim((-0.05, 1))
axB.plot(t, y, c='black')
axB.plot(t, y, 'o', c='#ff4500')
axB.set_ylim((-0.05, 1))
pos1 = axB.get_position()
pos2 = [pos1.x0, pos1.y0 + 0.3, pos1.width, pos1.height]
axB.set_position(pos2)

trans = [
    # (ax.transAxes + ax.transData.inverted()).inverted().transform for ax in 
    (fig.transFigure + ax.transData.inverted()).inverted().transform for ax in
    (axA, axB)
]

con1 = ConnectionPatch(
    xyA=trans[0]((0, 0)), xyB=(0, 0.1), coordsA="figure fraction",
    coordsB="data", axesA=axA, axesB=axB, color="black"
)
con2 = ConnectionPatch(
    xyA=(500, 0), xyB=(500, 0.1), coordsA="data", coordsB="data",
    axesA=axA, axesB=axB, color="black"
)
print(trans[0]((0, 0)))
axB.add_artist(con1)
axB.add_artist(con2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

The line on the left is supposed to go to `(0, 0)` of the upper axis, but it doesn't. The same happens btw if I try to convert to axes coordinates, so there seems be to something fundamentally wrong.

The reason why I want to use figure coords is because I don't actually want the line to end at `(0, 0)`, but slightly below the '0' tick label. I cannot do that in data coords so I tried to swap to figure coods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adapting the second example from [this tutorial code](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.4/gallery/userdemo/connect_simple01.html), it seems no special combinations of transforms is needed. You can use `coordsA=axA.get_xaxis_transform(),` if `x` is in data coordinates and `y` in figure coordinates. Or `coordsA=axA.transData` if `x` and `y` are both in data coordinates. Note that when using data coordinates you are allowed to give coordinates outside the view window; by default a `ConnectionPatch` isn't clipped.

The following code uses z-order to put the connection lines behind the rest and adds a semi-transparent background to the tick labels of `axA` (avoiding that the text gets crossed out by the connection line):

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import ConnectionPatch

t = [0, 6.297, 39.988, 46.288, 79.989, 86.298, 120.005, 126.314, 159.994, 166.295, 200.012, 206.314, 240.005, 246.301, 280.05, 286.35, 320.032, 326.336, 360.045, 366.345, 480.971, 493.146, 1080.117, 1093.154, 1681.019, 1692.266, 2281.008, 2293.146, 2881.014, 2893.178, 3480.988, 3493.149, 4080.077, 4092.298, 4681.007, 4693.275, 5281.003, 5293.183, 5881.023, 5893.188, 6481.002, 6492.31]
y = np.zeros(len(t))

fig, (axA, axB) = plt.subplots(2, 1)
fig.tight_layout()

for ax in (axA, axB):
    ax.set_frame_on(False)
    ax.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

axA.plot(t[:22], y[:22], c='black')
axA.plot(t[:22], y[:22], 'o', c='#ff4500')
axA.set_ylim((-0.05, 1))
axB.plot(t, y, c='black')
axB.plot(t, y, 'o', c='#ff4500')
axB.set_ylim((-0.05, 1))
pos1 = axB.get_position()
pos2 = [pos1.x0, pos1.y0 + 0.3, pos1.width, pos1.height]
axB.set_position(pos2)

con1 = ConnectionPatch(xyA=(0, 0.02), coordsA=axA.get_xaxis_transform(),
                       xyB=(0, 0.05), coordsB=axB.get_xaxis_transform(),
                       # linestyle='--', color='black', zorder=-1)
                       linestyle='--', color='darkgrey', zorder=-1)
con2 = ConnectionPatch(xyA=(500, 0.02), coordsA=axA.get_xaxis_transform(),
                       xyB=(500, 0.05), coordsB=axB.get_xaxis_transform(),
                       linestyle='--', color='darkgrey', zorder=-1)
fig.add_artist(con1)
fig.add_artist(con2)

for lbl in axA.get_xticklabels():
    lbl.set_backgroundcolor((1, 1, 1, 0.8))
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Hey, thanks! Sorry, I just realized that I didn't make this clear. The reason why I want to use figure coords is because I don't actually want the line to end at `(0, 0)`, but slightly below the '0' tick label. I cannot do that in data coords so I tried to swap to figure coods.

Comment: You could use `axA.get_xaxis_transform()` instead of `axA.transData` to have the x in data coordinates and the y in axes coordinates.

Comment: Great, thank you, this works. For completeness sake, how would you go about transforming into figure coords anyways (instead of axes coods)?

Comment: It would probably go like in the post you linked to.

Comment: But isn't that what I tried? I just really wonder  where the offset is coming from and why there is only one in x but not in y.

Comment: The problem in your code is that `ax.transData` doesn't yet have the correct transformation. The call to `tight_layout()` moved the positions of the axes but didn't update the internal transformations.  You can force a draw, calling `fig.canvas.draw()` just before you want to use `ax.transData`.

Comment: Calling `fig.canvas.draw()` before defining the transformations did the trick! But `tight_layout()` wasn't responsible alone, since removing it, didn't have an effect for me. Anyways, I also found another curious thing. If I execute the same code on another machine, the plot looks completely different (it's all moved to the bottom and partly cutoff). I updated matplotlib on that machine but that didn't help. Oh well.

Comment: I learned about ConnectionPatch after trying to chain some transforms manually and use Line2D. This is so much better, thanks for writing this answer!

Answer (score 1):

Possible answer to your last comment:
As you're dealing with figure coords, these can change depending on your screen resolution. So if your other machine has a different res then this could be why its changing. You'll have to look into using Axes coords instead if you don't want these random changes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).